# Asp.net Core MVC View Localization IsResourceNotFound = true in other than default locale

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-localization

I want to add localization in my ASP.NET CORE MVC  app with ar-SA as default localization. i configured every thing as per bellow links. my default locale is ar-SA and work good. but when i change locale to en-US  IsResourceNotFound is always true and resource not found

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1
https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-localization-deep-dive

Startup.cs

```
   services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
  var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
           new CultureInfo("ar-SA"),
           new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ar-SA"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
```

i also have try with .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder) and same resulty

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you mean that "IsResourceNotFound" is always true when you change the `DefaultRequestCulture` to en-US? The path of the resource file is correct , check if the key name on the view and the resource file are the same.

Comment: Did you find some solution?